# How do I print the values of all declared properties of an NSObject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, runtime

I want to override my object's description method to be able to print the values of all my declared properties. I know that I can do this by appending all the values to each other, one by one, but sometimes this is time consuming if you have a lot of properties.

I was wondering if there's an easy way to do this, by getting help from the runtime powers of Objective-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try [this solution](http://forrst.com/posts/Getting_a_dictionary_of_an_NSObjects_property_n-h2T) ?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface NSObject (PropertyListing)

// aps suffix to avoid namespace collsion
//   ...for Andrew Paul Sardone
- (NSDictionary *)properties_aps;

@end

@implementation NSObject (PropertyListing)

- (NSDictionary *)properties_aps {
    NSMutableDictionary *props = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        NSString *propertyName = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:property_getName(property)] autorelease];
        id propertyValue = [self valueForKey:(NSString *)propertyName];
        if (propertyValue) [props setObject:propertyValue forKey:propertyName];
    }
    free(properties);
    return props;
}

@end
```

Comment: Actually I had come across that web page but I couldn't scroll down the source code, possibly due to something about my browser. The original author should better display that code in a different way, so that people like me doesn't give up :) Thanks!

Comment: I used obj_runtime in my projects. But one of the project got rejected by the client thay said it is like hacking !!! And I don't want to reveal the name of them. You must have guessed the name of "big gun".

Comment: Hmm, it's good that you said this. I was just going to use this for debugging purposes, only in development time. I'd better remove that part before shipping the app then. Thanks!

Comment: what about properties with primitive data types?

Comment: I found this code useful for finding data quickly on my view's layer. For example, when adding a CAKeyframeAnimation to change a layer's opacity I found that it changes the UIView's layer's presentationLayer. I wouldn't have found this out without using the above category code so very useful not just for debugging, but for finding out more about the things I usually take for granted.