# Enumerate through objects properties

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, properties

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object) is an example of how the properties of a javascript object can be enumerated through. I noticed that the loop construct used was a `for...in` loop. Objective-C also has a `for...in` loop, so is the same behavior possible in Objective-C?

```
@interface Bar : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString * stringA;
@property (nonatomic) NSString * stringB;
@property (nonatomic) NSString * stringC;
@end

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Bar obj = [[Bar alloc] init];
    obj.stringA = @"1";
    obj.stringB = @"2";
    obj.stringC = @"3";

    for (NSString *property in obj) {
        NSLog(@"%@", property);
    }
}
```

Is this possible with Objective-C? If not, is there an alternative that would mimmic this behavior of iterating through an objects properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print the values of all declared properties of an NSObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881353/how-do-i-print-the-values-of-all-declared-properties-of-an-nsobject)

Comment: @EthanHolshouser Looked into it, like mine, it asked about seeing all of the properties of an object, but I want to see if it is possible to fast enumerate through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fast enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html)

```
Bar *obj = [[Bar alloc] init];
// ...
for (id elem in obj) {
   ...
}
```

requires that the class `Bar` conforms to the [`NSFastEnumeration` Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html), i.e. it must implement the

```
countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:
```

method. (This is the case for all Objective-C collection classes such as`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSSet`.)

So the direct answer to your question is *no*, you cannot use the fast enumeration syntax `for (... in ...)` to enumerate all properties of an arbitrary class.

However, it is possible to implement the fast enumeration protocol for a custom class.
Examples how this is done can be found here

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/FastEnumerationSample/Introduction/Intro.html
- http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/implementing-countbyenumeratingwithstat.html

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **yes it is possible**.

Here's some sample code of what you're trying to achieve.

**Header**

```
@interface Bar : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringA;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringB;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringC;

@end
```

**Main**

```
@implementation Bar
// don't forget to synthesize
@synthesize stringA, stringB, stringC;
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        unsigned int numberOfProperties = 0;
        objc_property_t *propertyArray = class_copyPropertyList([Bar class], &numberOfProperties);

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfProperties; i++)
        {
            objc_property_t property = propertyArray[i];
            NSString *letter = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
            NSString *attributesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getAttributes(property)];
            NSLog(@"Property %@ attributes: %@", letter, attributesString);
        }
        free(propertyArray);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.